# SQL select only one row out of duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update

My TableA is as below

```
Name            ID      Uname   Date        
------------------------------------------
Lname, Fname    1       uname1  20/12/2010  
Lname, Fname    2       uname1  15/07/2020  
Lname2, Fname2  3       uname2  21/12/2010  
Lname2, Fname2  4       uname2  16/07/2020  
Lname3, Fname3  5       uname3  22/12/2010  
Lname3, Fname3  6       uname3  17/07/2020  
Lname4, Fname4  7       uname4  23/12/2010  
Lname4, Fname4  8       uname4  18/07/2020
```

My TableB is as below

```
Uname   CopyID      
---------------
uname1  
uname2  
uname3  
uname4
```

I want to be able to update the latest record for TABLE B based on latest value of Table A i.e expected result

Expected TableB after update

```
Unameu  CopyID      
---------------
uname1  2
uname2  4
uname3  6
uname4  8
```

Code

```
UPDATE TABLEB
SET TABLEB.CopyID = TABLEA.ID
FROM TABLEA
INNER JOIN TABLEB ON Uname = Unameu
```

This is not working as, the join conditions selects 8 instead of 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a common table expression and over clause query as below

```
    WITH PatritionTable (RecordNumber,Uname,Id,Date) AS (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uname ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS RecordNumber,
                Uname,
                ID, Date
            FROM TABLEA)
    UPDATE TABLEB
    SET CopyID = p.id
    FROM TableB JOIN PatritionTable p
        ON p.uname=tableb.Uname
    WHERE p.RecordNumber = 1
```